# Display Table Data to the user in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Because nobody answered to my previous questions I need to find a different solution.

So, if you can **please** help me I would appreciate it very much.

I need to present to the **user that use the app** some table data by his name and id.

In other words I have a table data about flights reservations that the user performed earlier. 
that table contains flight reservations of all the users.

now I want that in case the user entered his user name and id I will show him all the data from the table that the columns userName and idNumber equals to his personal details.

How can I do this?

Comment: If no one answers a question, I suggest looking at the question and figuring out why that is. I suggest reading this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: Is the app winform, wpf, silverlight, asp.net, asp.net mvc? Your question as stated is so generic it would be hard to answer without being uselessly generic as well. I can't even tell if you're talking about the user of Visual Studio or the user of an app you create with Visual Studio.

Comment: Have you looked at `GridView`, `SqlDataSource`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where's the data coming from? If you're using a database, then databinding is going to be the simplest method of doing this. There are a ton of examples of databinding to a SQL database around the web. [Here's one](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0380__Data-Binding/DataBindingtoGridViewC.htm).

For showing only the selected user's data, you would add filters to the query appropriately. You can also search Google for ASP.net data binding and get a lot of examples.